# Add text to form label in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, label

I'm trying to add text to a form input on load.

For instance I want to add "(Required)" after "Last Name" in this example:

```
<div class="agile-group required-control">
  <label class="agile-label" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
```

My attempts are overriding the entire label:

```
$('.agile-group label').text('test');
```

I'm assuming I need to first capture the existing value and then add to it but no idea how, I'd guess something like this?

```
var text = $( this ).text();
$('.form-view label').val( text + "test");
```

Comment: Yes, you got idea: http://jsfiddle.net/ogLch0ay/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vv7m5ckz/10/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could add it to `text()`. Or use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.agile-group label').append(' (Required)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agile-group required-control">
  <label class="agile-label" for="last-name">Last Name</label><br/>
  <label class="agile-label" for="last-name">Last Name</label><br/>
  <label class="agile-label" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this seems to be the simplest solution.